# What is a sour additive for boiled potatoes that looks like a bean?

Tags: potatoes, additives

I recently tried boiled potatoes that had something added that looked like some sort of beans-like vegetables and tasted like green marinated olives. What is this vegetable?

Comment: Were they actually bean-shaped, i.e. oblong, or were they just round?

Comment: Good point. Somewhat between I'd say. But maybe actually just small and round.

Comment: Can you exclude caper berries?

Comment: @Marzipanherz actually as it turned out, it was exactly what I was talking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you mean capers. They're salty and sour.

They come in a variety of sizes, with the smaller ones pretty round, and the larger perhaps sometimes a bit more oblong.

See [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=capers&prmd=ismvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIj5ySlorZAhUT3GMKHcH4B6gQ_AUIESgB&biw=412&bih=604&dpr=2.63) to see if they look right!